# Acceleration is parallel to the position vector in a constant angular velocity motion

Tags: vectors, polar-coordinates

This question is taken from Davis, H. F. and Snider, A. D. 1979. Introduction to Vector Analysis. Allyn and Bacon, Boston.

> A particular moves in the plane with a constant angular velocity of $\omega$ but $r$ varies so that the rate of increase of its acceleration is parallel to the position vector $\vec{R}$. Show that $\ddot{r}=r\omega^2/3$

We know that the position vector in polar coordinates is

$\vec{R}=r\vec{u_r}$ and the acceleration vector is

$\vec{a}=(\ddot{r}-r(\dot{\theta})^2)\vec{u_r}+(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta})\vec{u_\theta}$

where $\vec{u_r}$ and $\vec{u_\theta}$ are polar unit vectors.

What I also understand from the question is that constant angular velocity means $\theta=\omega t$, which means $\dot{\theta}=\omega$ and $\ddot{\theta}=0$. Substituting into the equation of acceleration I get:

$\vec{a}=(\ddot{r}-r\omega^2)\vec{u_r}+(2\dot{r}\omega)\vec{u_\theta}$.
If this is parallel to the position vector $\vec{R}$, then

$\vec{a}=(\ddot{r}-r\omega^2)\vec{u_r}+(2\dot{r}\omega)\vec{u_\theta}=\alpha r\vec{u_r}$

Does it mean that $(2\dot{r}\omega)=0$? Do I understand the question correctly? Where do I go next?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: From the question $r$ is varying and $\omega$ is constant but presumably not zero, so I would expect that most of the time $(2\dot{r}\omega)\not= 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the vector derivative of the acceleration,

$$\vec{a}=(\ddot{r}-r\omega^2)\vec{u}_r+(2\dot{r}\omega)\vec{u}_\theta$$

and only derive for the anglar direction,

$$\dot{\vec{a}} = [(\ddot{r}-r\omega^2)\omega+2\ddot{r}\omega]\vec{u}_\theta+(\cdot)\vec{u}_r$$

where $\dot{\vec{u}_r} = \omega{\vec{u}_\theta} $ is used. Since the rate of change of the acceleration is parallel to $\vec{u}_r$, set its angular component to zero,

$$(\ddot{r}-r\omega^2)\omega+2\ddot{r}\omega=0$$

which yields,

$$\ddot{r} = \frac 13 r\omega^2$$

Comment: Thank you, I totally missed the part about the rate of change of acceleration.